# Hi All ,I want parameterize ,connection policy nodes like domain ,protocol in adapter.xml MFP..and pass values from external property file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

```
 <protocol>http</protocol>
 <domain>domainURL</domain>
 <port>80</port>
```

I am using `MFP 8.0`, and is there way to pass domain, protocol, port details from external property file to `adapter.xml` just like `MFP.server.getPropertyValue("property name")`

Answer (score 0):

For adapter, you can pass custom properties by defining a configuration file. For more details on how to do that, please check:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/#custom-properties